# How do I customize twitter bootstrap's various input sizes without using !important?

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap's input sizes only expand by width, whereas the buttons expand by both height and font size. (see pic) I'm trying to customize the inputs to expand by height and font size as well. (Note: they're fixing this for the next version, but I'm too impatient to wait)

[image]

So far I can only achieve this by using the `!important` hack to override the input css. I want to avoid using `!important` at all costs, because it is awful practice.

Currently, this is the code I have for expanding the height of `.input-large`. It does not work when I remove `!important`. I assume this is because inputs are given higher priority than classes (which I find absolutely silly, but correct me if I'm wrong).

```
.input-large {
width: 210px;
height: 44px !important;
margin-bottom: 10px !important;
line-height: 30px !important;
padding: 11px 19px !important;
font-size: 17.5px !important;
}
```

Is there any way I can achieve this **without removing the default input styling** and **not declaring `!important`**?

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xryQK/

Comment: If you use exactly the same selectors as TB (you should), override the instructions used by it if needed, define your own and these rules appear after those from TB, you shouldn't have to use `!important`. What does Firebug tell you about applied instructions and the ons struck(?) through?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Instead of using `!important`, you can use an *[attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)* which will override the default as it will be more specific than simply using a `class`. Not good with specificity concept? Refer [this](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) article.

For calculating the specificity of your selectors, you can use [this](http://specificity.keegan.st/) website.

<sup>[1]</sup> Using `class[attr=class]`

```
.input-large[class="input-large"] {
    width: 400px;
}
```

OR

<sup>[2]</sup> Using `tag[attr=class]`

```
input[class="input-large"] {
    width: 400px;
}
```

And using `!important` is not an awful practice if you use it in the right place.

---

Note that above selectors, <sup>[1]</sup> will make **all elements** `width` to `400px` having a `class` of `input-large` and in case of selector <sup>[2]</sup>, it will set `width` to `400px` for **all `input`** elements having `class` of `input-large`, so if you want, you can call *multiple classes* i.e `.class.class` on `input` tag and use the selector below..

```
.input-large.input-large-altered {
    width: 400px;
}
```

So this will select **any** element having both of these classes set, if you want to be more specific, and want to set only for `input type="text"` than you can always write even a more specific selector like

```
input[type="text"].input-large.input-large-altered {
   width: 400px;
}
```

So the above one will **only** target to `input` element whose `type` attribute is holding a `value` of `text` **AND** having both the classes i.e `.input-large` `.input-large-altered`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xryQK/1/)

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/xryQK/2/)

[**Demo 3**](http://jsfiddle.net/xryQK/557/) (Multiple classes)

Comment: Thank you for this! Do you know why it won't work as soon as add another class to it? http://jsfiddle.net/xryQK/3/

Comment: it should be `element[attribute=value]` :) http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

Answer (score 6):

AFAIK you just put your own customized css after the bootstrap's

example:

```
... Some codes here ...

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">
<style>
.input-large {
    width: 210px;
    height: 44px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding: 11px 19px;
    font-size: 17.5px;
}
</style>

... another code ...
```

Sorry, i forgot to delete the `!important`
The `!important` is not needed

Comment: She is avoiding the use of !important

Comment: If your style comes after bootstrap CSS loading, no need for !important !

Comment: @PéCé - nope, not for inputs.

Comment: @Michelle - Even if you also redefine it in your custom style with the `@media (max-width: 767px)` media query ? This media query comes from `bootstrap-responsive.css` file and may overload basic style from `bootstrap.css` on a smaller screen.

Answer (score 1):

If you're working off of the bootstrap .less files

an easy solution would be to add an extra entry like:

```
.form-fatter {
  // Set font for forms
  label,
  input,
  button,
  select,
  textarea {
    // Increase the default with 20%
    #font > .shorthand(@baseFontSize*1.2,normal,@baseLineHeight*1.2); 
  }
}
```

in your html

```
<form class="form-horizontal form-fatter">
...
</form>
```