# Bootstrap 4 overwrite rule

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

I am trying to change navbar link color in bootstrap 4 like that

```
.nav-link {
   color: red;
}
```

My scss file looks like that

```
@import '../../public_html/static/vendor/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';

.nav-link {
   color: red;
}
```

But without **!important** this doesn't work.

[image]

What have i missed?

Comment: It seems to be a weight problem. Have your tried .navbar-nav . nav-link { color: red; } ? And just in case (I guess you've already do that), check if your stylesheet is called after bootstrap.

Comment: Or this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29748260/cms-editing-scheme/29760437#29760437

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the first rule is more specific that the one you had added and therefore takes priority.

If you change your selector to:

```
.navbar-light
.navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: red;
}
```

Then it should work since it's the same level of specific-ness but further down in the source.

If you don't want to change the selector, you can always add `!important`, e.g.

```
.nav-link {
  color: red !important;
}
```

but it's generally not a good idea to throw in `!important` when it can solved in a nicer way as it might cause you problems further down the line.

Answer (score 1):

Give the full path to that link like..

```
.navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
   color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14022659/5374294) answer you can do the following for a full override:

```
.nav-link[class="nav-link"] {
    color: red;
}
```